# How to get a good parameter from an image for a future recognition

Tags: php, opencv, image-recognition

I am working on an image recognition app using php and I need to find a good parameter to store in a database. I have something like 5000+ image to loop trought so I need some kind of filter. Now I am using akaze ( based on opencv lib) and I store the number of keypoints returned from the `akaze_features` function but i think that parameter is not optimal. Does anyone here have experience with this kind of problem? Are there other good parameters besides keypoints to use for classification? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I feel like "parameter" isn't the right word here. What would the word be in your native language?

Comment: Have a look at, and maybe vote for ;-) my answers here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150946/find-input-image-id-passport-in-imagesdb-based-on-similarity/27151794#27151794  and also here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198558/matching-image-to-images-collection/25204466#25204466

Comment: Trying to improve spelling and grammar. Concentrate on keypoints.

Comment: Google "bag of words"

Comment: Im testing the phash :)